# Take snapshot of current photoshop file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, macos

I'm making a Mac OSX program where I need to take a snapshot (image file) the currently active window in Photoshop.

How would I go about this?

Comment: are you aware of [xScope](http://iconfactory.com/software/xscope)? it has a photoshop mode, in which its connect to a running photoshop instance that will transmit the active document.

Comment: and here is the [photoshop sdk](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop.html)

Comment: @vikinggosegundo Nice one.. thanks. Any links to tutorials on how to set it up in an OSX app and how to use it? Wasn't aware of xScope actually. Tried it out, but not so fond of it. Have you tried silkscreen (http://getsilkscreen.com)? Do you know of any other out there?

Comment: a bit too expensive to just try it out. also it says, you need to save to see the change on the ios device. with xscope you see it live.

Comment: Ya... found another one: http://bjango.com/mac/skalapreview/. Less expensive and you can hook it up to photoshop.

Comment: that was a purchase I wont regret. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Applescript inside Xcode to find photoshop and saving a copy of the current file. Not the best solution but it works.